# Python, array in class parameters don't have the right value when I call th class

Tags: python, arrays, class, parameters

guys I have a problem with my python code.

```
class BasketOption:

    def __init__(self,name,markets,typeO,numbersU,numbersA,maturity,strike):
        self.name = name
        self.markets = markets
        self.typeO=typeO
        self.numbersU=numbersU
        self.numbersA=numbersA
        self.maturity = maturity
        self.strike = strike
        self.cache = DateCache()

    def getnumbersA(self,numbersU):
        self.numbersA=np.empty(self.numbersU)
        return self.numbersA

    def getdates(self):
        return [self.maturity]

    def getmarkets(self):
        return [self.markets]

    def getweight(self):
        compt=0
        totalweight=0
        weight=np.empty(self.numbersU,dtype=float)
        for i in range(self.numbersU):
            totalweight+=self.getnumbersA(self.numbersU)[i]
        total=np.array([totalweight]*self.numbersU)
        weight=self.getnumbersA(self.numbersU)/total
        return weight

    def getsum(self,date):
        prices=0
        for i in range(self.numbersU):
            prices+= self.markets.getspot(date,i)*self.getweight()[i]
        return prices

    @timecached
    def getcf(self,date):
        if date == self.maturity:
            #FIXME: l'option peut aussi porter sur un forward, introduire
            # plutôt la notion de produit.
            if self.typeO=="call":
                return np.maximum(self.getsum(date) - self.strike, 0.)
        else:
            return 0
```

This is my class and I call it like this:

```
BasketOption(name="basket", typeO="call",numbersU=2,   numbersA=np.array([[2., 2.]]), maturity=1.,strike=110)
```

I don't have the good results so I searched on debug and I saw that `numbersA` did not take the values `2.` and `2.` in the array when I call it, it takes this:

```
ndarray: [  3.68777431e+180   1.04146313e-152]
```

I don't know why it take these values. Thanks.

Comment: Arent you missing `markets` argument that has no default value?

Comment: No it takes it I'm sure it just that I didn't show you this part of the code

Comment: Try putting a simple print() after initialization

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: everything works fine. You have probably not specified a key instruction that cause your bug and we can't help you. (I have set `market` argument to `None`, removed the `getcf()` method and set `cache` attribute to None instead of calling `DateCache()`)

Comment: [functools.partial(<class 'efficientmc.assets.BasketOption'>, numbersU=2, name='basket', numbersA=array([[ 2.,  2.]]), typeO='call', strike=110.0, maturity=1.0)]
this what i get when I use print()

Comment: There is no error of compilation I have the values I put when I call the class BasketOption except the right values of the array numbersA

Comment: ndarray: [  3.68777431e+180   1.04146313e-152] I have this in place of numbersA

Answer (score 1):

```
def getnumbersA(self,numbersU):
    self.numbersA=np.empty(self.numbersU)
    return self.numbersA
```

[`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) return an "empty" array -- i.e. with interior values unassigned -- for performance reasons.

I'm not sure what you're hoping `getnumbersA` will do, but right now every time you call `getnumbersA` you replace `numbersA` with something which is likely to look like this (arbitrarily choosing an argument):

```
In [36]: np.empty([1,2])
Out[36]: array([[  6.93278890e-310,   1.14700699e-316]])
```

which doesn't seem likely to be what you want.

Comment: It has to be that but I did this because I had an error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500000,) (2,)

Comment: self.markets.getspot(date,i) has shape (500000,) I know that w can't multiply two arrays of differents dimenions but normally with self.getweight()[i] I should have access to one elment of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I found my mistake it was here: numbersA=np.array([[2., 2.]]) I put 2 hooks, just need one.